# Word wrap not happening in UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I'm doing something that requires storing some text entered in a `UITextView`. It all works fine until the text is restored, then it is not wrapped in the UITextView (like it did when it was entered) but is truncated (just like a `UITableViewCell` does by default, tail truncation).

Once the text is in the `UITextView`, it is saved to a Core Data managed object with

`self.note.text = textNoteTableView.text;`

On creating the `UITextView` (which lives in a custom UITableViewCell)

```
UITextView *textView = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
textView.text = self.note.text;
```

The text seems fine and I can catch it being saved and being restored OK in the debugger. What I need to have happen is for the text to be displayed in the `UITextView` just like it was when originally entered, wrapped and not truncated. I have not set any properties on this object so I can't work out why it is not just behaving the way it would when a keyboard is the data source, or when it is restored from xib if I leave in the 
Lorem ipsum dolor default text.

Comment: does calling sizeToFit and/or setNeedsDisplay on textView help?

Comment: From what I read the behavior comes from having the UITextView inside the UITableViewCell - I chose to do it a different way as I saw no solutions in all the reports I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior comes from having the UITextView inside the UITableViewCell - I chose to do it a different way as I saw no solutions in all the reports I read.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
   textView.frame = CGRectMake(....); //set textView's frame to your original size
}
```

Above code will fix this problem.